Why does utilizing integrated graphics reduce CPU clock?
I have a laptop with an Intel Core i7-5600U CPU and Intel HD Graphics 5500 (integrated graphics).
I have noticed that when my GPU (integrated graphics) is in use / loaded, the CPU clock reduces signficantly. This seriously affects the responsiveness of the system - even though the CPU utilisation is not too high, the system is very sluggish when using the GPU. (I suppose because of the low clock speed).
See below images of what I mean:
Low GPU usage, high clock speed:

GPU in use, low clock speed:

ThrottleStop shows the following during a period of GPU load:

Why does using my integrated graphics slow down my CPU? Temperature?

TL;DR: Yes the GPU can output a lot more heat which causes the CPU to throttle itself to reduce temperature.
It slows down the CPU because the CPU and GPU are on the same package and both of them contribute to the overall package temperature and power draw. Your CPU has a power draw of 15W, with a maximum power draw of 25W according to Throttlestop.
In laptops the cooling system tend to be quite poor in comparison to desktops and can only remove so much heat before the processor has to start limiting itself by reducing clockspeeds.
When using the CPU only there is one key source of heat being generated, the CPU.
When using the GPU and CPU there are two sources of heat being generated, and due to the highly parallel nature of a GPU it is a far more efficient heat generator because you have a large number of small processors (stream shader processor units) operating in parallel.
The result is that in a laptop using the GPU can starve out the CPU of power or vice versa. When doing something purely GPU focused the GPU could cause the CPU to reduce clock speed, when playing games you end up with a sort of balancing act because the CPU being starved will slow down work being sent to the GPU which in turn will cool it down and allow the CPU to speed back up.

So theoretically, one can hypothesize that improving the cooling of the laptop may well allow the CPU to run faster even during heavy GPU load?

@M_D to an extent, yes. Cooling should help, but your CPU package might hit a power limit, and not quite reach full speed while the GPU is running, but better cooling should help a lot. If the laptop is old then there may be dust in the fans or the thermal paste might need to be replaced, otherwise a cooling fan underneath might help.
